# Reading the UID of a smart card

Tags: smartcard, uniqueidentifier, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard, serial-number

I use HID Omnikey Worbench. With this tool I can get a UID (unique identifier) for a contactless smart card. However I do not receive such a UID for contact cards.

Is it possible to read a UID from a contact smart card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact smartcards do not have a UID (or any anti-collision identifier).

Contact and contactless smartcards use a different physical communication medium (a wire vs. an RF field) and consequently require different (lower layer) communication protocols. With contact smartcards, a reader is only connected to exactly one card over a wired connection. With contactless cards, multiple cards could be within the range of the RF field of one reader. As a consequence, the smartcard reader needs to perform some form of anti-collision and enumeration in order to discover all (or at least one) contactless smartcard within its range. This is exactly where the UID comes in (at least in ISO/IEC 14443 Type A). The UID is used to uniquely address each card during anti-collision. Since there is no anti-collsion with contact cards (there is only one card connected to the reader anyways) there is no need for a UID with contact cards.

Comment: Exactly what I assumed. Thanks

Comment: Just another issue which may be related too:
Maybe you know what is the relationship between UIDs and Serial numbers? 
How does it look like on EMVs for instance?

Comment: @bafla UIDs are often used as serial numbers for tags/cards (particularly with ISO/IEC 14443 Type A cards/tags and with ISO/IEC 15693 tags). However, not all UIDs are suitable for use as serial numbers. E.g. there are cards with UIDs randomly assigend for every RF activation. Moreover, 4-byte UIDs must have collisions since there are more cards with 4-byte UID than there are valid 4-byte UIDs. Not all manufacturers guarantee to assign unique values to each tag/card. Finally, UIDs can easily be cloned.

Comment: @bafla EMV does not use the UID to identify cards. EMV uses account numbers to identify the payment account behind a card (or even a set of cards). Cards are *authenticated* using either public key cryptography (never protocol versions) or shared keys (legacy protocols). Hence, a card signs a message using some secret information in order to prove that it is a genuine card associated with a specific account number.